# inserting table row data upon onclick checkbox PHP and Ajax and MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

I have read similar topics, yet could not finish my code.

Short is: you tick a checkbox and this unchains an Ajax response that calls a function. This function gets the ID of the logged in user. Once I get the ID of the user, I am alright with the PHP script.

I have rewritten the code snippet; haven't tried it yet. Could say this is closer I hope.

I am using 2 scripts, 1 for the Ajax and the other the PHP.

Ajax:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getLoggedInUser()
    {

//IF THERE IS NOTHING CHECKED, THAT IS, STR == 0, THEN REMOVE WHATEVER WAS WRITTEN BEFORE

    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 



    // JUST CHECKING BROWSER COMPATIBILITY ISSUES FIRST

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }


          else

          {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }


// IF THE SERVER HAS THE RESPONSE READY

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
          {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            { 

     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


        }
      }
```

THEN ON HAVING TICKED THE CHECKBOX IT SENDS TO THE GETLOGGED IN FN
THE USER ID, AND THIS FUNCTION FORWARDS IT TO THE PHP SCRIPT CALLED
INSERT USER DATA, WHICH WILL DO JUST THAT.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insertUserData.php?$user="+str,true);


     xmlhttp.send();
  }


</script>
</head>


<body>


<?php $user = getUserId();?>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="asset" value="" onclick="getLoggedInUser($user)" /> I am potentially 

interested in this product or service<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Note:</b></div>


</form>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

======AND HERE THE PHP SCRIPT insertUserData.php  ===========

```
 <?php

 $user = $_GET['user'];


    // But now, as I indicated, we want the data corresponding to that ID



     $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);


        $query = "SELECT name, country
                  FROM profiles
                  WHERE id = '". $user . "';

        $result = @mysql_query ($sql);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        $name =  ($row['name']);
        $country =  ($row['country']);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (name, country)
        VALUES ($name, $country)");
        echo 'Your interest has been saved';

        mysql_close($con);
        ?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? As you can already see above, there's parse errors in your PHP code (you did not close the query string quotes correctly), and you appear to be mixing PHP and Javascript in your first code snippet.

Comment: It seems that you run mysql_query before mysql_connect

Comment: My advise would be to work through some basic PHP/MySQL and Javascript tutorials, and mess around with the code examples a little bit. You'll get the hang of it soon enough.

Comment: By the way, that PHP code seems to be missing a `"` on the end of the query.

Comment: I strongly suggest to go with jquery instead of pure JS. Things get much simpler and ajax calls are pretty easy plus there are plenty of tutorials on www (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp)

Comment: I've noticed that you've corrected the errors mentioned on my answer, `<? $user = getUserId(); ?> 
xmlhttp.open("GET","insertUserData.php?user=$user", true);`, it's a good start honestly but I don't believe you had a A+ at Harvard with such errors :)

Comment: yes, I did because that was in Oracle databases not in Ajax or PHP and as I have written several times the question was not the code, the parsing or any of that, because I copied it and pasted without NEEDING to care for nifty things and I am a Pharmacist anyway plus a MBA in Germany and 6 languages, English, French, German, Spanish, Italian and Russian, so I am not a coder

Plus I got a B in Java, a B in Bionformatics and Genomics, a B in Internet Protocols and Architectures though that was in 2001

Answer (score 0):

at least this:

```
$user = getUserId(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET","insertUserData.php?$user="true);
```

should be changed to :

```
<? $user = getUserId(); ?> 
xmlhttp.open("GET","insertUserData.php?user=$user", true);
```

it's not a straigh answer to your question but at least a starting point, also, make sure you enable errors by adding the following code at the top of your php file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: "I got my A+ at my Oracle class at Harvard with Dr.Pappadopoulos" , why don't you give Dr. Pappadopoulos a call ?

Comment: Since my posting here, where I mentioned my own website, I am having a series of automated spam registrations in it, despite the catcha verification code. I am logging all IPs and together with the ISPs and they will be dealt with to the full extent.